# Adding an ORM to an existing padrino application

Tags: ruby, sinatra, padrino

I'm new to ruby, sinatra and padrino,
so it might be a silly question, but:
Is there a way to add an orm to an existing application ?

My problem is that I have created an application with the following command line:

```
$ padrino-gen project sample_blog -a mysql -b
```

(I thought that a default ORM was selected.)
Then tried to add a model:

```
$ padrino-gen model post title:string body:text
<= You need an ORM adapter for run this generator. Sorry!
```

How can I add the orm without recreatting the whole application?
It's not very important now, since the application do not contains anything,
but I plan latter to add tests, and I would like to know if it's easy.

Thanks for your tips for a beginner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open `/project-name/.components` with your editor and add

```
:orm: activerecord
```

Comment: You will also need to add this to your Gemfile. `gem 'activerecord', :require => "active_record"`. Finally you will need to manually create a `config/database.rb` file to define the database connection.